# C# converting datagrid view cells in to a single string

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, buttonclick

The following method is used by me to convert the cells in a datagrid view into a single string and print the string in the console when button is licked!

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String file = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    file = file + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```

But i get the following error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured' with the code line dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); highlighted! How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string file = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                       if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value!=null)
                         {
                      file+=dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                         }
                       else
                         {
                           file+="";
                         }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
```

I think your loop for `j` is wrong. Let try this.

Comment: Thanx for the answer when both first and second answers combine it works properly! :D

Comment: i had just updated, it seems that some columns in your grid dont have value, try the updated code.

Comment: Thanx this works well

Answer (score 0):

You must check if value exists in cell like this ->

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value!=null)
{    
file = file + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer when both first and second answers combine it works properly! :D